# ionViewDidLoad() Method doesn't work?

Tags: angular, email, authentication, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to implement an Email Authentication everything works fine but the Methode ionViewDidLoad doesn't get recognized? I tried the Methode ionViewWillLoad() but didn't work too.

Does someone know what could be the problem?

My Code: 
home.ts

```ts
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';
    import {NavController, IonicPage, NavParams, ToastController} from 'ionic-angular';
    import { AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
    @IonicPage()
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    export class HomePage {

      constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private toast: ToastController,
                  public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
      }



      ionViewDidLoad(){
        this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data => {
          if (data.email && data.uid) {
            this.toast.create({
              message: `Welcome to APP_NAME, ${data.email}`,
              duration: 5000
            }).present();
          }
        })
      }
    }
```

Comment: your implementation of `ionViewDidLoad` looks correct. Do you try to step through it in debugger or `console.log("something")` in the first line to validate that the function realy doesn't get called? It looks to me like `authState` never emit or `date.email` and/or `date.uid` are invalid

Comment: even when i generate a new Page the ionViewDidLoad doesn't work so i don't know what is wrong? i generated a Home Page and this method gets initialized `code ionViewDidLoad() {console.log('ionViewDidLoad HomePage');} ` but it doesn't work as too?

Comment: does I have to use the Methode somewhere in the Project?

Comment: when you didn't get the output in the console there is another problem. ionViewDidLoad() get's called in each Page i created (not in Components etc.)

Comment: I also suffering the same issue, ionViewDidLoad not getting called. Did u find any solution yet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you calling your HomePage component ? The ionViewDidLoad() hook is called when your component which implements it is pushed/popped from a NavController as said in the documentation : https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

If the call of your component is not made by your NavController, the hook may not be called. So then you may use the constructor to call  your function.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, IonicPage, NavParams, ToastController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, 
              private toast: ToastController, 
              public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public navParams: NavParams) 
   {
     this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data => {
      if (data.email && data.uid) {
        this.toast.create({
          message: `Welcome to APP_NAME, ${data.email}`,
          duration: 5000
        }).present();
      }
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: `code async login(user: User) {
    try {
      const result = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
      if (result) {
        this.navCtrl.push('HomePage');
      }
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  } `  I call it in a login.ts File where i implemented a login function. How do you mean to use the constructor to call the function?

Comment: okay thanks that works but but it is not the best solution i think?

Comment: In your situation the behavior is the same as ionViewDidLoad(), but it's not resolving why the ionViewDidLoad() hook is not called for sure.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm still questionning about the hook which is supposed to be working. If I find something about it I'll come back to you ;-)

Comment: i imported the project in visual studio and the error is gone i used web storm before :D

Comment: in the life cycle of the page creation, what is the order in which the IonViewDidLoad and the constructor get called?

Comment: The constructor is called in first.